# How to set primary monitor with AMD Catalyst Control Center installed

Tags: 14.04, ati, multiple-monitors

when I run `xrandr`, I get a list of my connected monitors (which are DFP5 and DFP6)
DFP5 is an HDMI connected TV which I want to be my secondary monitor as it is smaller,
and DFP6 is a DVI connected monitor which I want to be my primary monitor as it is the bigger of the two.

However, when I run `xrandr --output DFP6 --primary` Nothing happens, and the windows keep opening first of all on my smaller TV Monitor.

I have also edited my ~/.config/monitors.xml file and set the primary tag to yes for my big monitor, and no for my small TV monitor, and it has not made a difference.

I have the AMD catalyst control centre installed, and it is showing that my TV monitor is monitor 1 (and therefore primary), but I don't want it to be the primary, I want it to be secondary.

If you can help me get this sorted, I would greatly appreciate it, thanks!

Here's a screenshot of amdcccle showing my monitor config. I want the monitor on the left to 1, and the monitor on the right (the TV monitor) to be 2.

http://storage5.static.itmages.com/i/14/0724/h_1406217562_3506723_70676df955.png

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu's System Settings in the Display panel, the selected monitor is set as the primary monitor. It's pretty unintuitive.

Comment: I am aware of this, but it doesn't work. I think it's to do with the AMD control panel